# How to load a CSV file and then convert it into a javascript array (Compare input of form with external csv file to display specific content)

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript but this is what I've pieced together from here and w3schools. 
Apologies if something similar already exists.

I want to create a page where people with a 6-character code can find out what they've won.

In my example;
I have 5 toy cars and 5 rubber duckies to give away. 
(codes will eventually by randomised) 
If I was to upscale this to 500 toy cars and 500 rubber duckies I believe there has to be a better way than what I have created. (below)

Is there a way to compare the input with a csv file (or other file type located online) that I can use to validate the if/else statements in 
"function compareinput()" ?

I'd prefer javascript solution as opposed to PHP.

See fiddle here; https://jsfiddle.net/tn5Lp3mc/ 
*(apologies in advanced for not compartmentalising my code, I don't know how to use jsfiddle)*

```
function compareinput() {
var x = document.getElementById("forminput");
var text = "";
var i;
var varbl;
for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
    text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
}

varbl = text.toUpperCase().substring(0, 6);

if (varbl == "RD1234" ||
    varbl == "RD4567" ||
    varbl == "RD7894" ||
    varbl == "RD8454" ||
    varbl == "RD9854") {
    displayRubberduck ();
}
else if (varbl == "TC5678" ||
    varbl == "TC1234" ||
    varbl == "TC9874" ||
    varbl == "TC8989" ||
    varbl == "TC1212") {
    displayToycar ();
}
else {
    displayInvalidcode();
}
```

}

Comment: Would it be helpful to rephrase your question as "how to load a CSV file and then convert it into a javascript array? Once you achieve that, your problem becomes a matter of finding values from an array. There is a pretty good library for parsing CSV in javascript: https://www.papaparse.com/

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the question.

Comment: _“I'd prefer javascript solution as opposed to PHP.”_ - why? So that everyone can go look up what a valid code would be, by simply requesting the CSV resource (the URL of which you of course won’t be able to hide) themselves …?